# Can I create a dummy INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT trigger so I can use MERGE with INSTEAD OF DELETE?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to utilize the SQL Server 2008R MERGE functionality to manage parent child relationship records in a join table.

The join table represents many-to-many relationships, so it has two foreign keys for the same primary key. Accordingly, `ON DELETE CASCADE` cannot be used. In it's place I am using a trigger on `INSTEAD OF DELETE` and deleting the join records, thus removing the constraint so I can complete the originally intended delete operation.

Unfortunately, when I try to use MERGE in this scenario I get the following error.

```
The target 'Content' of the MERGE statement has an INSTEAD OF trigger on some,
but not all, of the actions specified in the MERGE statement. In a MERGE statement,
if any action has an enabled INSTEAD OF trigger on the target, then all actions
must have enabled INSTEAD OF triggers.
```

Here's the T-SQL for reproducing this problem. I have included commented out drop and select statements for convenience.

```
CREATE DATABASE [TestDatabase]
GO

USE [TestDatabase]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Content] (
    ContentID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Title varchar(255)
)
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Content]
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Content
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContentID)

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Attachment] (
    ParentContentID int NOT NULL,
    ChildContentID int NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attachment]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Attachment]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [ParentContentID] ASC,
        [ChildContentID] ASC
    )

ALTER TABLE dbo.Attachment
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Attachment_ParentContent
    FOREIGN KEY (ParentContentID)
    REFERENCES dbo.[Content] (ContentID)
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 

ALTER TABLE dbo.Attachment
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Attachment_ChildContent
    FOREIGN KEY (ChildContentID)
    REFERENCES dbo.[Content] (ContentID)
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trContentInsteadOfDelete
    ON dbo.[Content]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM dbo.[Attachment]
    WHERE [ParentContentID] IN (SELECT [ContentID] FROM deleted)
    OR [ChildContentID] IN (SELECT [ContentID] FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM dbo.[Content]
    WHERE [ContentID] IN (SELECT [ContentID] FROM deleted)
GO

INSERT INTO [Content] ([Title]) VALUES ('a'), ('a'), ('a'), ('b')
GO

INSERT INTO [Attachment] ([ParentContentID], [ChildContentID])
    VALUES (1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 4)
GO

MERGE [Content] AS target
USING (VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (NULL, 'b')) AS source ([ContentID], [Title])
ON target.[ContentID] = source.[ContentID]
WHEN MATCHED AND target.[Title] != source.[Title] THEN
    UPDATE SET target.[Title] = source.[Title]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Title]) VALUES (source.[Title])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY source THEN
    DELETE;

/*
USE master
DROP DATABASE [TestDatabase]

SELECT * FROM [Content]
SELECT * FROM [Attachment]
*/;
```

<strike>Is there any alternative to adding triggers to `INSTEAD OF INSERT` and `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` without having to explicitly delete any constraining records in the Attachment table before deleting records from the Content table?</strike>

I could temporarily disable the trigger, but then I'd have to explicitly delete the constraining records in the Attachment table.

I'm concerned that adding additional triggers just to accommodate the MERGE statement defeats the purpose of using the MERGE statement.

Update: Is there a way to create a dummy INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE trigger to enable me to continue to use the MERGE?

Comment: I"m not sure what answer you expect here: the error is explicit and the requirement is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.105).aspx) so the best you can hope for is a workaround such as creating dummy triggers that do nothing.

Comment: @Pondlife, I'd rather retain the ability to use MERGE and find a better way to clean up the orphaned join records in the Attachment table. I'm hoping somebody has a better way to achieve the same result I illustrate in the code above. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick, but I wonder about the affect on performance.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trContentInsteadOfDelete
    ON dbo.[Content]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM dbo.[Attachment]
    WHERE [ParentContentID] IN (SELECT [ContentID] FROM deleted)
    OR [ChildContentID] IN (SELECT [ContentID] FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM dbo.[Content]
    WHERE [ContentID] IN (SELECT [ContentID] FROM deleted)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER trContentInsteadOfInsertUpdate
    ON dbo.[Content]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.[Content] (
        [Title]
    )
    SELECT
        i.[Title]
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Content] c ON i.[ContentID] = c.[ContentID]
    WHERE c.[ContentID] IS NULL

    UPDATE c
    SET
        c.[Title] = i.[Title]
    FROM dbo.[Content] c
    JOIN inserted i ON c.[ContentID] = i.[ContentID]
GO
```